# Universal Image loader fails to load images sometimes

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal image loader and I get quite large numbers of images failing to load for users every day. 
I'm using this code to get my errors to analytics.

```
public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
  try
  {
    String fail = failReason.getType().toString();
    String fail4 = failReason.getCause().toString();
    String sum = fail + " " + fail4;
    EasyTracker.getTracker().sendException(sum, false);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    EasyTracker.getTracker().sendException(e.getMessage(), false);
  }
}
```

Most of the time it catches exception, as getType, or getCause is null. This issue is seen on devices with 2.1-2.3 android versions, but there are some reports from newer version like 4.0.4 or even 4.2.2. So I can't really tell what caused the image failing to load

Another issue is `IO_ERROR java.io.EOFException`, which is mostly seen on newer android versions.

Third of most common errors are out_of_memory errors... The images I am trying to load are no bigger than 1mb, but I need to have ScaleType.Exactly, but while loading larger images I am not caching them in memory or disc, to reduce possibility of out_of_memory, but it still does occur pretty often.

My configuration:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(xxx.getApplicationContext())
.threadPoolSize(4)
.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
.imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(xxx.getApplicationContext(),10 * 1000, 30 * 1000)) 
.build();

if(!ImageLoader.getInstance().isInited())
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

// options is used for images smaller in size (5kb-150kb)
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub)
.showImageOnFail(R.drawable.failed)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.build();

// options2 is used for images big in size (300kb-1,2mb)
options2 = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub)
.showImageOnFail(R.drawable.failed)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE) // NONE because I need to have full size bitmap loaded
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.build();
```

Could anyone tell me how could I optimize my imageLoading to get less failed to load images? Because I feel like I am loosing users some because of these constant failings to load images.

**Update**
As I changed the code as nostra suggested on `onLoadingFailed`, I'm now seeing that all the reports which does not have `.getCause()` are "DECODING_ERROR" and all these are reported by android 2.2-2.3.6 versions, none from newer ones. Yet still large portion of my users are on older androids, any idea how to reduce this decoding_error? I checked app myself on older androids, and images do load most of the time, but `DECODING_ERROR` is reported most often on analytics. Second on most popular reasons is still the same `IO_ERROR java.io.EOFException`

**Update 2**

Customized Downloader as nostra suggested, reduced threadPoolSize to 3 set up an extra loading - if loading failed try to load again for one time before giving up. I see failings to load decreased about 30%. But still do occur - 100 decoding errors (exclusively only on 2.2-2.3.6 versions) , and 160 EOF errors (4.0 and up) in 3 days from 500 daily active users.

**Update 3**

Latest updated version gets far less decoding errors and EOFExceptions, I think mainly because I try to reload the same image if it fails to load the first time. But.. I am now face another issue: No space left on device `java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)`. I am using LimitedDiscCache.

Answer (score 5):

`failReason.getType()` can't be `null` but `failReason.getCause()` can. You should check it to prevent NPE.

`failReason.getCause()` can be `null` if you deny network by `ImageLoader.denyNetworkDownloads(true)` or if decoding error occurred. This is because Android can't decode image by some reason.

BTW I recommend you to use `.cacheOnDisc()` even for big images (`options2`).
And maybe try other memory cache implementation? E.g. `LruMemoryCache`.

I don't know the reason of `java.io.EOFException` but can you detect which network is used in that time? Mobile or WiFi? Maybe try use `ImageLoader.handleSlowNetwork(boolean)` to switch between network types.

**UPD:** Also try to reduce thread pool size. Maybe it helps to prevent DECODING ERRORS.
**UPD2:** Decoding error can be caused by web site redirect to web page. You can try extend `BaseImageDownloader` and add empty string for "User-Agent" header in request.

```
public class MyImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

private static final int MAX_REDIRECT_COUNT = 5;

public MyImageDownloader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

protected InputStream getStreamFromNetwork(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = connectTo(imageUri);

    int redirectCount = 0;
    while (conn.getResponseCode() / 100 == 3 && redirectCount < MAX_REDIRECT_COUNT) {
        conn = connectTo(conn.getHeaderField("Location"));
        redirectCount++;
    }

    return new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
}

protected HttpURLConnection connectTo(String url) throws IOException {
    String encodedUrl = Uri.encode(url, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(encodedUrl).openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
    conn.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
    return conn;
}
}
```

Or since UIL 1.8.5:

```
public class MyImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {
    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = super.createConnection(url);
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use casheInMemory at all, to reduce possibility of out_of_memory? I'm doing my best to reduce size for images on server side(compressing and showing thumbnailed images), but I still get out_of_memory reported in analytics. I myself fail to reproduce any of these errors. Except for EOFException, it very rarely occurs while I try to fast swipe through already cached images, and some of them fail to load with EOFException. For internet connection I can't tell exactly, but most of my users are not on wifi, so they might have slow connection

Comment: Also try to reduce thread pool size. Maybe it helps to prevent DECODING ERRORS.

Comment: Updated answer. UPD2 to prevent DECODING_ERROR.

Comment: Thank you for not forgetting this issue, I will add your fix in nearest update, and post with the results.

Comment: I have updated my question with results. If you still have any ideas what I could try please share them :)

Comment: @NOSTRA , thank you so much!!  I've spent few days on it and finally it turns out to be the redirecting issue. But I don't quite understand how it solve the redirecting problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have never used Universal Image Loader but in the last few weeks a couple of really good alternatives have been released, they might be worth a look.

The first is Volley, Google's new networking lib announced at I/O 2013
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

The second is Square's Picasso. The Square team do some really great work with their Android libs. 
http://corner.squareup.com/2013/05/picasso-one-dot-oh.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those. But still the question is about Universal Image loader:)