# android universal image loader out of memory

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm loading about 50 images. In my activity I have this configuration

```
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
        .diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024)
        .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

in binderdata

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(uri, holder.iv_img);
```

Some images are loaded, but some are not and I get `OutOfMemory` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this tips from [Useful Info](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info)

> If you often got OutOfMemoryError in your app using Universal Image
>   Loader then:
>
> 1. Disable caching in memory. If OOM is still occurs then it seems your app has a memory leak. Use MemoryAnalyzer to detect it. Otherwise
>      try the following steps (all of them or several):
> 2. Reduce thread pool size in configuration (.threadPoolSize(...)). 1 - 5 is recommended.
> 3. Use .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) in display options. Bitmaps in RGB_565 consume 2 times less memory than in ARGB_8888.
> 4. <s>Use .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)</s> (Your already use this tips)
> 5. Use .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null) in configuration

Hope this helps!!

Comment: threadPoolSize determines the number of threads running simultaneously. If you set a large pool size, speed of the UI can significantly be reduced , e.g list scrolling could slow down. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603245/universal-image-loader-fails-to-load-images-sometimes @Nostra recommend to use 3.

Answer (score 0):

1.I would suggest you to checkout **Image Management Library by Facebook** that is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that is pretty awesome and mature as compared to other Image Loading Library.

2.Fresco handles all the things caching of images with 3 Tier architecture ( `BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE`, `ENCODED_MEMORY_CACHE` and `DISK_CACHE`). **It also reduces OOM(Out Of Memory) issues**. When image in a view goes out of screen it automatically recycles the bitmap, hence releasing the memory.

3.Fresco has `SimpleDraweeView` as custom image view which supports Rounded Corners and Circles link and supports Animated(`.gif`, `.webp`) as well as Normal Images(`.jpg`, `.png`).

Comment: Is Fresco can create thumbnail of video(.mp4, .3gp etc.)?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad is it a youtube video?

Comment: I don't think Fresco does that, it is an image loading library not extracting images/frames from videos.